# при отправке POST запроса через HttpWebRequest нужно передать параметры в URL

Tags: httpwebrequest

при отправке POST запроса через HttpWebRequest нужно передать GET параметры в URL:
http://site.ru?mode=1
POST параметры приходят, но сервер не видит GET параметров.

Создается запрос

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(this.url + "?mode="+mode);

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

// добавление post параметров
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот это:

```
public class Requester
{
    public List<Cookie> Cookies = new List<Cookie>();
    public string UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0";

    public WebResponse Get(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest rq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        rq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        foreach (var cookie in Cookies)
        {
            rq.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
        }

        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);

        ((HttpWebRequest)req).UserAgent = UserAgent;

        req.Method = "GET";

        return req.GetResponse();
    }
```